# not getting the output in emulator in android studio

Tags: android-emulator

I am not getting the output in emulator in android studio where i had run the simple code it was showing that install successfully finished and launching app but in emulator it was still in home page . can any one have any inputs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t11w1.png)

i just tried simple kotlin hello world i was expecting to print hello World

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as in emulator it was showing that my application keeps stopping when i run the code as everything is correct , you know how to look in to logcat and edit the code